# Elasticsearch aggregate on term multiple times per different time range

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate a field by each half of the time-range given in the query. For example, here's the query:

```
{
"query": {
  "simple_query_string": {
    "query": "+sitetype:(redacted) +sort_date:[now-2h TO now]"
    }
  }
}
```

...and I want to aggregate on term "product1.keyword" from now-2h to now-1h and aggregate on the same term "product1.keyword" from now-1h to now, so like:

```
"terms": {
  "field": "product1",
  "size": 10,
}
```

^ aggregate the top 10 results on product1 in now-2h TO now-1h,
and aggregate the top 10 results on product1 in now-1h TO now.

Clarification: product1 is not a date or time-related field. It would be like a type of car, phone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use `now` in your query，you must make product1 field as `date` type，then you can try as below：

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dataAgg": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "product1",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "now-2h",
            "to": "now-1h"
          },
          {
            "from": "now-1h",
            "to": "now"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top10": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and if you can't change product1's type ，you can try [rang agg](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html)，but you must write the time explicitly instead of using `now`

Comment: The product1 field is not a date, unfortunately. It would be, for example, like a different brand of car. I want to see the top 10 hits of car-type for one hour, and then the top 10 hits of car-type for the next in this example.

Comment: try range agg query